# Using field calculator to associate lines with countries

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a shapefile of power transmission lines and a shapefile of countries.

Ideally I want to use the field calculator to identify and add two new columns: of the country where the transmission line begins and the country where the transmission line ends.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use this expression on the line layer and replace the layer name (`countries`) and fieldname (`Name`) accordingly for the country name of the line's start point. Replace `start_point` with `end_point` to get the name of the country at the line's end point:

```
array_sort (
    array_foreach (
        overlay_intersects ('countries', $id),
        case
        when 
        intersects(
            geometry (get_feature_by_id ('countries',@element)),
            start_point ($geometry)
        )
        then 
        attribute (get_feature_by_id ('countries', @element), 'Name')
        end
    ),
    0
)[0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to use the same code within the field calculator? I want to add the start points and end points to the field attribute table so that I can export it.

Comment: Yes, this is the expression for the field calculator as well. Labels were just to demonstrate that it works :-)